# Сбой при подключении по FTP Ubuntu

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

При подключении к серверу по ftp пишет: (фото добавляю)[image: Выводимая ошибка]

> Ошибка:   Соединение прервано после 20 секунд неактивности
> Ошибка:   Невозможно подключиться к серверу

В чем не может быть ошибки:

- Имя пользователя и пароль введены без сомнения верно
- Порт 21 открыт
- Пользователь user создан (и личная папка).
- Локальное подключение через `telnet localhost 21` - работает нормально и логгируется в логах vsftpd.
- статус vsftpd - `active`

Подскажите пожалуйста чего я не учёл..

Код конфигурационного файла прикладываю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался!

Причина оказалась проста.. VPS на джино без подключенной услуги "Выделенный IP" не разрешает доступ к FTP. Доступ разрешен только по SFTP, что кстати даже надёжнее(хотя по слухам медленнее FTP).

Во всём мне помогли разобраться в службе поддержки jino[image: введите сюда описание изображения]